# Aspect testing - can't get right value of aspects bean's property

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

**Aspect**

```java
@Configurable
@Aspect
public class FilmCounter {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> filmCounts = 
            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    @Pointcut(
        "execution(* soundsystem.CompactDisc.play(int)) " +
        "&& args(filmNumber)" )
    public void filmPlayed(int filmNumber) {}

    @Before("filmPlayed(filmNumber)")
    public void countFilm(int filmNumber){      
        int currentCount = getPlayCount(filmNumber);
        filmCounts.put(filmNumber, currentCount + 1);

        System.out.println("filmNumber " + filmNumber + " contains in ? " + filmCounts.containsKey(filmNumber) + " then filmCount = " + filmCounts.get(filmNumber));

    }

    public int getPlayCount(int filmNumber){
        //System.out.println("filmNumber " + filmNumber + " contains in ? " + filmCounts.containsKey(filmNumber) + "");

        return filmCounts.containsKey(filmNumber)
                ? filmCounts.get(filmNumber) : 0;

    }
}
```

**Configuration class**

Under AspectJ runtime lib so not needed `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation

```java
@Configuration
public class FilmCounterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CompactDisc filmDisk(){
        FilmDisc cd = new FilmDisc();
        cd.setTitle("1981's Melody Films");
        cd.setArtist("Kishor Kumar");
        List<String> films = new ArrayList<String>();
        films.add("Sanam Teri Kasam");
        films.add("Akhari Rasta");
        films.add("Hum Apke Hai Koun");
        films.add("Dil Hain Ke Manata Nahi");
        films.add("Hum Sath Sath Hain");
        cd.setFilms(films);

        return cd;
    }   

    @Bean
    public FilmCounter filmCounter(){
        return new FilmCounter();
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=FilmCounterConfig.class)
public class FilmCounterTest {

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog(); 

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Autowired
    private FilmCounter counter;

    @Test
    public void testFilmCounter(){

        cd.play(1); System.out.println("counter.getPlayCount(1) = " + counter.getPlayCount(1));
        cd.play(2);
        cd.play(3);
        cd.play(3);
        cd.play(3);
        cd.play(3);     

        /*assertEquals(1, counter.getPlayCount(1));
        assertEquals(1, counter.getPlayCount(2));
        assertEquals(4, counter.getPlayCount(3));
        */

        System.out.println("Film 1 = " + counter.getPlayCount(1));
        System.out.println("Film 2 = " + counter.getPlayCount(2));
        System.out.println("Film 3 = " + counter.getPlayCount(3));

    }

}
```

When running the above test case I get the following output:

[image: Console log]

The image shows that the console log output for the first method call `cd.play(2);` looks OK, but after invoking `System.out.println("Film 1 = " + counter.getPlayCount(1));` it shows the wrong result (it should display "4" but displays "0").

Comment: FYI, I have reformatted your question because you used quotations instead of normal or bold text. I also took care of making your inline picture visible. Please learn StackOverflow syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Question: It is a little hard to understand what you want to explain. I am specifically puzzled by this remark: "Under AspectJ runtime lib so not needed `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation" What does it mean? That you use LTW (load-time weaving) and full AspectJ instead of Spring AOP?

Comment: Sorry. I could not explain that, But now i want to say that I need not use @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation to configure that FilmCounterConfig class because I am using STC IDE and in that i have configured AspectRuntimeLibrary in my project's classpath. that i wanted to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is going on, looking at your console log: There is an active aspect instance recording your method calls, but probably not the same one as is wired into your test. This would explain the discrepancy between the aspect log output versus the test log output.

If you add `System.out.println(this);` to the `countFilm(int)` advice and `System.out.println(counter);` to the test case, I guess you will probably see two different object IDs.

If I am right, something is wrong with your with your bean wiring. Please provide feedback here in a comment.

Comment: Yes. you are right the output by doing this is following                                  In the testFilmCounter() and counter = soundsystem.FilmCounter@762efe5d
filmNumber 1 contains in ? true then filmCount = 1
In the countFilm(int filmNumber) and this = soundsystem.FilmCounter@5d22bbb7

Comment: But why this is happening?  This example is from Spring in Action 4th Edition Book with slightly change (in name of classes only)

Comment: You forget another "slight" change: Instead of Spring AOP you use AspectJ. Even though I never used Spring in my whole life, I know that you need to use `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` or alternatively `<context:load-time-weaver/>`. Maybe you already do that, I have no idea. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-configure) also mentions something like `<bean id="my-aspect" class="com.xyz.MyAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">`. Just read the manual and work it out by yourself or simply switch back to Spring AOP.

Comment: I also tried this '@EnableLoadTimeWeaving' but like using '@EnableAspectJAutoProxy' this also shows error .......  [Failed to parse configuration class [soundsystem.FilmCounterConfig];]

Comment: I really think you need to learn a little Spring. If the config class cannot be parsed then obviously there is some syntax error, missing import or whatever. I cannot solve every little problem for you, especially because I never used Spring in my life. I told you what your aspect problem is, the rest you should figure out by yourself - no offense meant. If you cannot find out, I suggest you start over, downloading the free source code from the book's web site and making a new try instead of trying to fix your messed up project.